# Why different speed between oracle and postgresql?

Tags: oracle, postgresql

In postgresql

```
select * from test where text123 = '1'

"Index Scan using ix_test on test (cost=0.57..12619.44 rows=6980 width=343)"
"  Index Cond: ((text123)::text = '1'::text)"



select * from test where text123 = ''

"Seq Scan on test (cost=0.00..11918891.20 rows=209355618 width=343)"
"  Filter: ((text123)::text = ''::text)"
```

first query result returns immediately. but second isn't.

In Oracle, it has same plan with postgresql but second query result returns immediately.

What can I do for second query in postgresql?
And why second query is so slow?

please help me...

Comment: Try `analyze test;` in postgresql. It should just recompute the stats on the test table so the query plan can be the best available. Change the select list when you test the query again, eg `select text123 from test where text123 = '1'` so you can be sure it's re-preparing the query plan. Report back with the result - this may or may not fix it immediately.

Comment: First, thanks about your advise. I tried your suggestion. but, it is not working. Can you give another way for me?

Comment: In Oracle '' is the same as NULL. In PostgreSQL they are not the same. No idea why comparing to '' (empty string) should take longer than comparing to '1' - perhaps there are very few rows with '1' but many with ''?  Try where text123 IS NULL in PostgreSQL and see what happens.

Comment: It isn't full query. It is subquery for another main query. This subquery return result ''. so I tested like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second query

```
select * from test where text123 = ''
```

does very different things in PostgreSQL and Oracle.

In PostgreSQL `''` means "a string of zero length". Thus in PostgreSQL the query means

```
Return all fields in all rows of table test where the text123 column
is equal to a string which is zero characters long
```

In Oracle, however `''` means `NULL`. Thus in Oracle this query means

```
Return all fields in all rows of table TEST where the TEXT123 column
is equal to NULL
```

and because *nothing*, not even NULL, is *ever* equal to NULL the query will return nothing.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you! I got useful knowledge from you.